# Search in Objects without loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am currently working for optimization and performance the problem Objects are like:

```
   var scheduleFee = {
                poor = {level1:25,level2:25,level3:25} ,
                good = {level1:15,level2:20,level3:25} ,
                vgood = {level1:10,level2:15,level3:20}
            {;
```

Now I want to find **good** in **schedule fee**
My main concern is performance and optimization Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please start with a valid javascript array/object, what is bad, to use good as key?

Comment: Your `scheduleFee` declaration is incorrect.

Comment: `scheduleFee ` is not a valid array.

Comment: its array of object and valid

Comment: not conecrn with only array , my model is array of objects

Comment: If you don't know anything about the array, you cannot do without a loop (or recursion). But if for example it is sorted, or you have a lookup table pointing to indices then you could do something with. Please tell us more about your use case so that we can suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: @KumailHussain So first start by correctly declaring an array of objects.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if this is not valid then come up with ur notation

Comment: @Bergi its use case i am receiving this data from backend and I want to search without loop

Comment: @KumailHussain, it is not our notation, it is your requirement. if you look for some ideas, you could use an object with the wanted keys, like `good` and add the nested object. then access is working with `object.good.level2`.

Comment: `var scheduleFee = {poor: {level1: 25, level2: 25, level3: 25}, good: {level1: 15, level2: 20, level3: 25}, vgood: {level1: 10, level2: 15, level3: 20}};`

Comment: @KumailHussain if you are receiving this data from backend then share that data.

Comment: @KumailHussain That it comes from the backend is no information about the *structure* of the data. The only reasonable suggestion I could make is to let the backend only deliver the values that you need.

Comment: @NinaScholz I know my notation is little weird because it is from backend so I cant re invent a new one

Comment: @KumailHussain Btw, do you have any actual *performance problem*? If not, then there's no reason to optimise. And no reason to avoid loops anyway.

Comment: @KumailHussain but you could fix the backend.

Comment: yeah Performance is key thing for me, loops are not preferable in our orrganization

Comment: @Bergi its not a solution to fix the backend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151939/discussion-between-kumail-hussain-and-bergi).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I know how to convert, the problem is remaining in the same model can we find a solution or not

Comment: Look, your problem is either that 1) your backend is spitting out some text format that doesn't easily map to JavaScript (i.e. not JSON) and you need help parsing it to a valid JavaScript object/array structure; or 2) you have a valid JavaScript structure and need help getting the required values out of it. So, which is it?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you join the chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the updated structure with an object, you could use the given keys directly, without iterating. All you need is the right [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

> ```
> object.property    // dot notation
> object['property'] // bracket notation
> ```

```js
var scheduleFee = { poor: { level1: 25, level2: 25, level3: 25 }, good: { level1: 15, level2: 20, level3: 25 }, vgood: { level1: 10, level2: 15, level3: 20 } },
    key = 'good',
    level = 'level2'

console.log(scheduleFee[key][level]);
```